# Error Of JQuery in Internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

I am running on of my project on Internet Explorer 8 i.e. IE8 and i am getting the following errors. this project is successfully run on the Chrome and Mozilla as well as IE11 also but i want to use IE8. is there any way to solve the Errors..
[image]

Comment: Mention the errors...

Comment: *and* show the code :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: "And"

Comment: this is the only error i m getting.

Comment: Is jQuery called before the scripts that need it?

Comment: i am getting the Error Jquery is undefined..

Comment: @Vishnu: IE8 has a (rudimentary) debugger, so you can walk through your code to see where it's failing.

Comment: Share the code and included jquery files..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is used JQuery Version?

[jQuery 2.x does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.](http://jquery.com/download/)

Check the version of JQuery please.

---

Version Checking!

Check your html(index.html) file

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
        src="/lib/jquery/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

File name have version name like "jquery-1.11.1.min.js"

In this case, version is 1.X, then this version support IE 8.

If your script link(src) don't have version like "jqeury.js",

Open the file.

You can find the comment of version like below code.

```
/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */
```

Comment: can you please tell me hw to check the version of JQuery??

Comment: My JQuery version is 2.x so now what exactly i have to do for the working in IE8

Answer (score 0):

jQuery 2.0 dropped support for some browsers. See the post at

http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/

No more support for IE 6/7/8: Remember that this can also affect IE9 and even IE10 if they are used in their “Compatibility View” modes that emulate older versions. To prevent these newer IE versions from slipping back into prehistoric modes, we suggest you always use an X-UA-Compatible tag or HTTP header. If you can use the HTTP header it is slightly better for performance because it avoids a potential browser parser restart.

Keep jQuery 1.9 if IE 6/7/8 are a concern.